# Cannot find module 'dotenv/types'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js, dotenv

Im using next.js and trying to set an environment variable - I have installed dotenv ofcourse by im being told that the module cannot be found and have no earthly idea as to why. Why might something like this be happening?

The dotenv is in my dependencies, But when i run dotenv --version i get told 'bash command not found'

I should say that the below code is probably not relevant to the problem.

in my .env file at the root of the doc i have

```
API_URL = http://localhost:1337
```

Then in my config file i have

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {
  env: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias['components'] = path.join(_dirname, 'components');
    config.resolve.alias['public'] = path.join(_dirname, 'public');

    return config;
  },
};
```

Im getting this on the the console:

```
 Loaded env from C:\Users\sidtu\Documents\Websites\next-example\.env
 Cannot find module 'dotenv/types'
 code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
```

Comment: What if you do `$ npm install dotenv `?

Comment: I have install dotenv - I get no errors and everything is fine. I also ran the extended version

Comment: Check if there are a dotenv/types folder in your node_modules, if not, install it with: npm i dotenv/types. If is it there, try to delete your node_modules and install it again: npm install

Comment: @ST could you try installing `$ npm install --dotenv-extended` also?

Comment: After checking that file i can see that it is actually there which is strange. I have deleted the node modules and ran npm install - Same issue

Comment: Yeah = I already tried the extended version but no luck

Comment: Are you using typescript or javascript

Comment: next.js so i guess javascript would be closest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"The dotenv is in my dependencies, But when i run dotenv --version i get told 'bash command not found'"* - That is typical behaviour for a npm package, only packages that are installed globally should be accessible from the command line.

If you are just using `dotenv` in weback, use [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) instead.

If you are having trouble getting `.env` files to work with React see [this blog](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5)

Comment: Awesome - You're a life saver. I was following the permissions route. Everyone i have watched was using the normal dotenv and it worked for them which is strange

Answer (score 0):

Use **npm** to install dotenv-types

`$ npm i -g dotenv-types`

Usage:

`$ dotenv-types -h`

Source:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-types